# Typesafe Config : Reference current directory?

Tags: config, typesafe-stack

It is possible to include system properties into configuration file, as explained in [docs](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

Looks like ${?VARNAME} recognizes only system properties (passed with -D option).

I need to be able to recognize environment values, in particular - $PWD

How can I do that in the configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

This should just work already. Typesafe config searches both system properties and environment variables by default.